# How to dynamically add an Item to a model then display the model within a view

Tags: javascript, qml

I am trying to add a dynamically instantiated QML component to a view as I need it to be added at a certain index and display at the top. The component is created correctly but when it is added to the model it does not display, how can this be solved? Here is my code:
main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2



ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true

    Timer{
       interval: 700
       repeat: true
       running: true
       property int counter : -1;
       onTriggered: {
           counter++;
           var component;
           var sprite;
           var object;
           component = Qt.createComponent("Recta.qml");
//           sprite = component.createObject(project, {"x" : 100, "y" : -300, "name" : "Joshua" + counter});
           object = component.createObject({"name" : "*****" + counter})
           project.insert(0, object)

       }
    }
    ListModel{
        id: project
    }


    ListView{
        id: lview
        width: 310
        height: 1080

    }

}
```

recta.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

    Item{
        width: 300
        height: 300
        property string name;
        Rectangle{
            width: 300
            height: 300
            color: "teal"
            Text{
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: name
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fixed main.qml code for you.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true

    Timer{
       interval: 700
       repeat: true
       running: true
       property int counter : -1;
       onTriggered: {
           counter++;
           project.insert(0, {"name":"*****" + counter});
       }
    }

    ListModel{
        id: project
    }

    ListView{
        id: lview
        width: 310
        height: 1080

        model: project

        delegate: Recta {
            name: model.name
        }
    }
}
```